# How to get sent data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I send data in this way:

```
<form method="post" enctype="text/plain action="Func">
```

And I have a function:

```
protected void Func(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

How Can I get data which I sent?

Comment: Can you please clarify if this is MVC or just WebForms, as you can't do this in WebForms. You only ever have 1 form anyway, so it would be down to looking at the Request.Form[] or responding to the event that generated the postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the signature of your method it looks like you're using WebForms. Is this right? If so, in WebForms you don't write the `<form>` tag like this, it's easier to create a new ASPX page (Web Form) and use the default. Everything on the page goes in one form. To "get the data", you just access properties on your page's controls, e.g. `myTextBox.Text`.

If you're coming from PHP and this all sounds a bit weird, you may want to be using ASP.Net MVC. In which case, it's generally easier to use an HTML Helper method for the form, something like:

```
using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   ...
}
```

But then the signature of your method is all wrong, you'd be better defining a View Model class, and having something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Func(ViewModel postedModelData)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get data of a post you can do that

```
Request.Form["nameOfyourControl"]
```